# Can I store a node process variable in JSON?

Tags: json, variables, environment

I am currently in the process of migrating an Express app to Heroku.

To keep sensitive information out of source, Heroku uses config vars which are assigned by to process variables of the same name.

Currently, I am loading my keys using .json, such as:

```
{
  "key": "thisismykey",
  "secret": "thisismysecret"
}
```

However, if I try to load the variables in via Heroku's format:

```
{
  "key": process.env.KEY
  "secret": process.env.SECRET
}
```

Obviously, I get an error here. I would assume that it is possible to load these values into JSON, but I'm not sure. How could I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To generate JSON with these values, you would first create a JavaScript object and then use `JSON.stringify` to turn it into JSON:

```
var obj = { "key": process.env.KEY
            "secret": process.env.SECRET };

var json = JSON.stringify(obj);
// => '{"key":"ABCDEFGH...","secret":"MNOPQRST..."}'
```

Comment: Alright, so it looks like there's no way to do this natively in JSON. Thanks for your help.